# Why did Miss Hardbroom and Indigo Moon discontinue their friendship in The Worst Witch?

Tags: the-worst-witch

Indigo Moon had a friend named Joy. She never heard back from her. It turned out Miss Hardbroom was Joy but she didn't want to tell Indigo that. Later, Indigo planned to use forgetting powder to forget that Joy existed. Then Miss Hardbroom admitted that she was Joy but can't have that kind of friendship anymore because she's her teacher. Why does the fact that she's her teacher prevent it?

Comment: After watching certain episodes in the fourth season, I can safely say "because Hecate Hardbroom would prefer Indigo lost her memory rather than confront their relationship".

Comment: Because it's weird for a fifty year old and a thirteen year old to be friends?

Answer (score 1):

If Miss Hardbroom looked at Indigo as a friend and not as a student, there would be cases of open favoritism. A teacher should be someone to talk to with respect. A friend is someone to talk to casually. Besides, look at the age difference! Miss Hardbroom is literally 30 years older than Indigo. I doubt such a friendship would work.

Comment: The think is a teacher's job is to teach. The student can't figure out all by themself how to do everything. So it's the job of the teacher to teach them how to do it. It's their job to make it clear what they have to do and what they don't have to do. If the teacher is all casual like a friend, the student will not be able to figure out when something is a rule and when something is just a suggestion for how to play with them like a friend.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's to do with the fact that a teacher's job is to teach. A student doesn't have God like abilities to enable their teacher to take for granted that if they give them any kind of wrong instruction including suggestion of an activity like a friend, they will recognize that it's not actually something they have to do and talk back about it. If the teacher teaches the wrong way, the student will be unable to believe the teacher wouldn't properly teach them what it is they're supposed to do and learn it the wrong way.